# Windows Service hosting WCF crashing with System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I have a Windows Service hosting multiple WCF services deployed on Windows Server 2008 R2. It randomly crashes every few days with the following information:

```
Application: Gibunco.Peninsula.Business.ServiceHost.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException
Stack:
   at System.Runtime.Fx+IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

I tried researching the problem with the available stack trace but could not find any lead. Unfortunately this creates a problem for live users.

Anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: You cannot use debugger or stack trace to diagnose `OutOfMemoryException` since it can occur at any place in the code where you allocate new memory using `new` operator. The only way to fix it is to use a profiler tool and improve application's memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This process has been running smooth for a few years now, without any kind of memory problem so it's just suspicious why does it crash so frequently and with the same error message?

Comment: Are you running on 32 bit or 64 bit OS? What version of .net runtime are you using?